# Rounding to an integer - Rounding control field?

Tags: c, assembly

I am  trying to write a function named roundD that rounds its first argument to an integer value according to the mode specified by its second argument.

I will be writing the function in assembly language, using gcc’s inline assembler. I do not want to use any predefined functions..

I think i need to set the Rounding Control field of the FPU Control Word in accordance with the second argument?. I also think i need to restore the original value of the Rounding Control field before roundD returns?

I am trying to figure out how i should accomplish this in the right order..

Should i use the Control Word of the FPU?

1. Do i load the value into the FPU?
2. Use the control word - BIT FIELDS to do the calculations?

like: The RC field (bits 11 and 10) or Rounding Control determines how the FPU will round results.

Can someone give me an example of how i would use the RC fields?
Or am i way off base with what i need to do?

I am going off this page..
http://www.website.masmforum.com/tutorials/fptute/fpuchap1.htm

is this a good page to go from?
What else do i need to google for information? 
Any help is much appreciated..
I think i just need a detailed analysis of the steps i need to take to accomplish this..

This is what i have so far..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PRECISION           3
#define RND_CTL_BIT_SHIFT   10

// floating point rounding modes: IA-32 Manual, Vol. 1, p. 4-20
typedef enum {
ROUND_NEAREST_EVEN =    0 << RND_CTL_BIT_SHIFT,
ROUND_MINUS_INF =       1 << RND_CTL_BIT_SHIFT,
ROUND_PLUS_INF =        2 << RND_CTL_BIT_SHIFT,
ROUND_TOWARD_ZERO =     3 << RND_CTL_BIT_SHIFT
} RoundingMode;

double roundD (double n, RoundingMode roundingMode)
{

return n;


}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
double  n = 0.0;

printf("Rounding - Assembly");
if (argc > 1)
    n = atof(argv[1]);

printf("roundD even %.*f = %.*f\n",
       PRECISION, n, PRECISION, roundD(n, ROUND_NEAREST_EVEN));
printf("roundD down %.*f = %.*f\n",
       PRECISION, n, PRECISION, roundD(n, ROUND_MINUS_INF));
printf("roundD up   %.*f = %.*f\n",
       PRECISION, n, PRECISION, roundD(n, ROUND_PLUS_INF));
printf("roundD zero %.*f = %.*f\n",
       PRECISION, n, PRECISION, roundD(n, ROUND_TOWARD_ZERO));

return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is another similar question with an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35518449/3857942

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if your environment includes the improved C99 floating point support? C99 defines the functions `fegetround()` and `fesetround()` to get and set the current floating point rounding mode.  The `rint()` function can then be used to round according to the current rounding mode.

Comment: I want to do it myself. I do not want to use a pre built function. I am trying to learn c with assembly.

Answer (score 1):

```
 __ftol          proc near
 var_C           = qword ptr -0Ch
 var_4           = word ptr -4
 var_2           = word ptr -2
                 push    ebp
                 mov     ebp, esp
                 add     esp, 0FFFFFFF4h
                 fstcw   [ebp+var_2]
                 wait
                 mov     ax, [ebp+var_2]
                 or      ah, 0Ch         ; 00001100
                                         ;
                                         ; ROUNDING CONTROL FIELD
                                         ;     The rounding control (RC) field of the FPU
                                         ;     control register (bits 10 and 11)
                                         ;
                                         ;     Rounding Mode                  RC Field Setting
                                         ;
                                         ;     Round nearest     (even)       00b
                                         ;     Round down        (toward -)   01b
                                         ;     Round up          (toward +)   10b
                                         ;     Round toward zero (Truncate)   11b
                 mov     [ebp+var_4], ax
                 fldcw   [ebp+var_4]
                 fistp   [ebp+var_C]
                 fldcw   [ebp+var_2]
                 mov     eax, dword ptr [ebp+var_C]
                 mov     edx, dword ptr [ebp+var_C+4]
                 leave
                 retn
 __ftol          endp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 oldcw   dw   ?

  fstcw oldcw     ;get the current Control Word to retain all setting bits
                  ;not related to the rounding control (RC) bits
  fwait       ;to insure the storage instruction is completed
  mov   ax,oldcw
; and   ax,0F3FFh ;clears only the RC bits, leaving all other bits unchanged
                  ;not necessary here because both bits will be set
  or    ax,0C00h  ;this will set both bits of the RC field to the truncating mode
                  ;without affecting any of the other field's bits
  push  eax       ;use the stack to store the modified Control Word in memory
  fldcw [esp]     ;load the modified Control Word

  fxxxx           ;other FPU instruction(s) needing the truncating mode

  fldcw oldcw     ;restore the previous Control Word
  pop   eax       ;clean-up the stack
                  ;this could also retrieve a 16-bit or 32-bit integer
                  ;possibly returned by the "other FPU instruction(s)"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have a memory variable called hwcntrlwd with the bits correctly set:
(intel syntax)

```
mov eax,[hwcntrlwd]
fstcw ax
```

Comment: So, in my case i could do something like: 
mov eax,[n - ROUND_NEAREST_EVEN] // whatever enum mode?
fstcw ax

Comment: `fstcw` needs a memory destination, not AX.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48981197/fstcw-assembly-operand-type-mismatch.

Comment: @Peter Cordes  It can be either AX or a memory location. https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fstsw:fnstsw  I remember quite well several years ago when a graphic library assembly file started choking on the latest GAS with gcc, and we all had to change FSTCW EAX to FSTCW AX

Comment: You linked `fstSW` (status word), which does have an AX destination form.  But your answer uses `fstCW` (control word) which doesn't; see my linked answer. from my previous comment.  That's the problem.

Comment: @Peter Cordes  I didn't even see that! <facepalm> Sorry.